# How make fullscreen iframe videos With jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Help me to solve. I want to make fullscreen video means (allowfullscreen) with jquery. Please help me how to do that.
This is my code for iframe videos

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="275" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tum8KtULX7M" width="100%"></iframe>

 <iframe frameborder="0" height="275" 
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RtdT8Tjaehg" width="100%"></iframe>

  <iframe frameborder="0" height="275" 
   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tbXhvBUKN_Y" width="100%"></iframe>


   </div>
```

Please check it. Thank you so much In advance.

Comment: Youtube api already has fullscreen feature. Really not clear what your specific problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment @charlietfl i know this is you tube api feature but i want do this from jquery when user click on video then in video show option allowfullscreen. this is i want from jquery. Please help me if you know how to do this

Comment: it's help from requestallowscreen but i didn't know how to use this. Thanks

Comment: You can't access a cross domain iframe due to *"same origin policy"*. Need to use Youtube api to do whatever you want

Comment: So you mean that this is no option without api :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this once:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tum8KtULX7M" width="100%"></iframe>

 <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" 
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RtdT8Tjaehg" width="100%"></iframe>

 <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" 
   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tbXhvBUKN_Y" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```